# What is prefetchDataSource in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode9

I was working on one screen and I seen `prefetchDataSource` for `UITableView` in the list of `datasource` and `delegate`. Can someone please explain me what is use of it and how to use it ?

Attaching screenshot for reference.[image]

Comment: just like prefetch in collectionview. https://andreygordeev.com/2017/02/20/uitableview-prefetching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewDataSource Prefetching will help you to improve smooth scrolling and performance for your TableViews by prefetching the data in advance for the next rows that will become visible while user is scrolling down.

**prefetchDataSource**  is the object that acts as the prefetching data source for the table view, receiving notifications of upcoming cell data requirements.

UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching protocol for UITableView and UICollectionView is available since iOS 10. The delegate function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) will be called when a row is near the display area, you can call the web API and load them inside this delegate function.

[image: A reference from https://fluffy.es/prefetching/]

For more information refer:-

https://fluffy.es/prefetching/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching?language=objc

Comment: A link and a plagiarized paragraph is not an answer.